# imacros - undefined path

Tags: javascript, firefox, imacros

I'm playing around with imacros for the first time and wanted to do a simple script which would have several macros in an array, and then the javascript file would randomly run one of the macros each time. For some reason however I'm getting an error when I try running that stating that my path is undefined (error code -991). I'm clueless as to why I'm getting this error however, since my path is correct. Is there some setting that I may be unaware of that I need to alter in order for my simple dummy script to work?

```
var options = new Array();
var i;
options.push("testAutomation/test1.iim");
options.push("testAutomation/test2.iim");
options.push("testAutomation/test3.iim");
options.push("testAutomation/test4.iim");
var randOption = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];

for (i=0; i<4; i++){
iimPlay(options[randOption]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are getting the actual value here, but are using it as an index:

```
var randOption = options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)];
// options["testAutomation/test1.iim"] => Undefined
```

`randOption` in this case will be the actual string values, so for example `options["testAutomation/test1.iim"]` is not defined, but `options[0]` is.

You want to use the index number instead, so remove `options[...]`

```
var randOption = Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length);
// options[0] => "testAutomation/test1.iim"
```